# Is there a way to reset lodash's once() so the next time it is called as though the first time?

Tags: javascript, lodash

For context, I'm writing an automated test for a function that takes a while to calculate its result. Therefore, I want to make sure the result is cached. Lodash's [once function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#once) does what I need, but if I want to unit test my function, `once` doesn't reset between tests so it introduces test pollution.

Is there a way I can "reset" `once` between tests so at the beginning of every test it acts like it's being called the first time? This is `once`'s source code:

```js
  function once(func) {
    return before(2, func);
  }

  function before(n, func) {
    var result;
    if (typeof func != 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(FUNC_ERROR_TEXT);
    }
    n = toInteger(n);
    return function() {
      if (--n > 0) {
        result = func.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      if (n <= 1) {
        func = undefined;
      }
      return result;
    };
  }
```

FWIW, it's easy for me to solve this problem by avoiding `once` and writing my own one-off cache. Alternatively, I could monkey patch/stub `once` or `before`. But I'm asking this for academic purposes: if there is another way to reset `once`, I think it'll teach me a new technique I didn't know existed--a technique that'll be useful for other things down the line.

Comment: Just call `_.once()` again. Each time you call it it creates a new cached function.

Comment: It's not a matter of resetting `once` itself: that function is deterministic, and there's nothing to reset. Are you hoping to "reset" is the function returned from `once`(/`before`)? Most likely you need a spy to make `once` behave differently when your component calls it.

Comment: I just discovered [memoize](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#memoize) which seems to be built for this use case?

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure how to do that when it's written like this inside the production code: `export const myCachedFunc = _.once(myFunc);`

Comment: Assuming you're using Jest: [`jest.spyOn(_, 'once')`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype)

Comment: @DanielKaplan That does invalidate my suggestion. It sounds like you may need to mock `_.once()` for testing. Sorry, I'm not sure how to do this in detail.

Comment: @jabaa actually I'm using Jasmine, but I think the solution is to use `memoize` instead of `once`: the former gives you access to the cache and the ability to clear it.

Comment: I usually write my tests without modifying my code. I would try avoid replacing functions. If you only need this functionality for the unit tests, I would recommend to find a different approach. Jasmine also has [`spyOn`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/5.0/global.html#spyOn). Maybe you should first read the tutorials in the documentation.

Comment: @jabaa Actually I'm using Sinon for spies because I've found it can test-double things that Jasmine can't (or couldn't... I discovered this years ago). ¶ Personally, I let my tests dictate my production code, as IMHO, it's one of the main tenants of TDD (I mean this in general; there's always nuance to these things). ¶ This is likely attributable to coincidence, but after using `memoize` in my test, my production code ended up needing access to the `memoize` cache, too.